# ubuntu: sudo apt install edb-debugger: package not found?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, отладка

Пытаюсь поставить на чистенькую ubuntu 16.04 (учебная машина) отладчик edb.

Делаю это так, как написано в тысяче мест в интернете:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install edb-debugger
```

Пишет, что пакет не найден.

Видимо, у всех, у кого это работает, уже был подключен нужный репозиторий с пакетами, но какой?

Связываться со сборкой из исходников не хочу, потому что этот ад зависимостей между версиями буста и qt я не разгребу никогда.

В ubuntu 18 и 20 версии все работает "из коробки". Но на учебнйо машине я не могу обновить то, что там понаставлено.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какой магической командой подключается нужный репозиторий?

Спасибо

Comment: а почему вы так не хотите собрать из исходников, судя по документации https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger/wiki/Compiling-(Ubuntu) это не так сложно

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас попробую по ЭТОЙ документации...

Comment: Супер-совет, просто когда заходишь в git проекта - там урезанная команда, которая все эти зависимости не ставит. а инструкция то была совсем перед глазами, надо было просто перейти по ссылке...

Comment: естественно, *not found* — [нет такого пакета в репозиториях для версии xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=edb-debugger&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)